# Justify cv-entries in awesome-cv

Tags: awesome-cv, justification

I am using the template awesome-cv for my resume: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV

I am wondering how I can justify the description of the cv-entries. The description is usually itemized.

This is my preferred result.

[image]

This is the definition of cv-entries:

```
% Define an environment for cventry
\newenvironment{cventries}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \begin{center}
}{%
  \end{center}
}
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
  \end{tabular*}%
}
```

And this is how they are used:

```
\cventry
    {Software Architect} % Job title
    {Omnious. Co., Ltd.} % Organization
    {Seoul, S.Korea} % Location
    {Jun. 2017 - May. 2018} % Date(s)
    {
      \begin{cvitems} % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
        \item {Provisioned an easily managable hybrid infrastructure(Amazon AWS + On-premise) utilizing IaC(Infrastructure as Code) tools like Ansible, Packer and Terraform.}
        \item {Built fully automated CI/CD pipelines on CircleCI for containerized applications using Docker, AWS ECR and Rancher.}
      \end{cvitems}
    }
```

I have tries adding `\justify` from the ragged2e package at a couple of places. But it did not work or I was not doing it properly.

Do you have any other idea.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which part of the cventry exactly would you like to justify? Could you add a sketch of the desired output to your question?

Comment: You do not show its definition but I would guess the columns `L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}` mean left and right aligned text so you could use standard `p` instead `p{\textwidth - 4.5cm} p{4.5cm}`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to justify the description. I have edited the question to provide more information